# Does tab character render correctly in email signature

Tags: email, html-email, email-client

I want to create a plain text email signature, and use tab to align my columns. Can I guarantee it will be correctly displayed on all email clients?

Is there a better way to achieve what I want - which is a very simple two column email signature where the columns are left aligned, and it looks exactly the same on all email clients?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. This is not possible in plain text.

Best practice in plain text is to use spaces for aligning. This only works on monospace fonts. Use HTML tables and HTML formatting of your email if you want to have control over rendering. This is supported by all major email clients.